# An Object of a type convertible to 'ActionResult' is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have a list of European union countries.

When a user enters their country of residence on the registration form, I run a `foreach` block to check if the country they live in is in the EU. If it is, I assign `true` to a boolean I've declared of `isEuropeanUnion`. If not, I assign `isEuropeanUnion` to `false` and pass that onto my new user object to be saved in the db.

However, because I'm not exiting out of the `foreach` block on a `true` hit, it's always returning `false`. When I try to add a `return` to the `foreach` block, I get the red squiggly saying

> An Object of a type convertible to 'ActionResult' is required.

```
//check if the user resides in a EU country
var EUCountries = dbContext.EuropeanUnionCountries.ToList();

foreach (var country in EUCountries)
{
    if (model.CountryOfResidence == country.Name)
    {
        isEuropeanUnion = true;
        return;
    } else
    {
        isEuropeanUnion = false;
    }
}

var user = new ApplicationUser {
    UserName = model.Email,
    Email = model.Email,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
    CountryOfResidence = model.CountryOfResidence,
    IsEuropeanUnion = isEuropeanUnion
};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think you might mean: `bool isEuropeanUnion = EUCountries.Any(eu => eu.Name == model.CountryOfResidence);` since `SingleOrDefault` doesn't return a `bool`

Comment: @RufusL Yes, I meant exactly that (but on `dbContext.EuropeanUnionContries`), thanks

Comment: @RufusL that worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, it's just a shortcut for what you have. To fix your existing code, you'd just need to replace `return;` (which exits the method) with `break;` (which exits the loop)

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess that you are trying to invoke your code inside the action which returns `IActionResult` so in such case you cannot use `return;`, you must return an object which inherits from the IActionResult.
I would try to do something like this instead:

```
var flag = false;
foreach (var country in EUCountries)
{
    if (model.CountryOfResidence == country.Name)
    {
        // if you don't use isEuropeanUnion inside the foreach loop
        // the code makes no sense 
        isEuropeanUnion = true;
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        isEuropeanUnion = false;
    }
}

if (flag)
{
    // do something
}
```